# PHP preg_replace the backslash \

Tags: php, preg-replace

Really simple question: how can I `preg_replace` the backslash character?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Yes, but you need to escape it. When using it in the regexp use `\\` to use it in the replacement, use `\\\\` (that will turn into `\\` that will be interpreted as a single backslash).

Comment: $htmlRes = preg_replace("~\\~", "", $htmlRes);
Warning: preg_replace(): No ending delimiter '~' found

Comment: That should be `$htmlRes = preg_replace("~\\\\~", "", $htmlRes);`. When PHP parses the string, the escape sequences are processed, and it's interpreted as `"~\\~"`, which is then parsed by the regexp engine, as a single back slash.

Answer (score 8):

You need to escape the backslash: `\\`

From the [manual on `preg_replace`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php):

> To use backslash in replacement, it must be doubled (`"\\\\"` PHP string).

Alternatively, use [`preg_quote`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-quote.php) to prepare a string for a `preg_*` operation.

Comment: @ajk are you using single quotes or double quotes?

Comment: $the_name = preg_replace('\\\\', 'u', $the_name);

Comment: @aj in that  case, I *think* using only two backslashes should work. Single-quoted and double-quoted strings have different escaping rules

Comment: Just looking to replace the backslash with nothing ("Susan\'s" -> "Susan's")

Comment: Yeah, I tried that too and it didn't work. In both cases, it ends up returning an empty string.

Comment: also, there isn't going to be a "u", I was just testing.

Comment: Okay, I got a solution: the php stripslashes() function. http://php.net/manual/en/function.stripslashes.php Worked like a charm.

Answer (score 5):

You could try

```
$a = "\\\\";
$a = preg_replace('/\\\\/','/',$a);
```

Output:

```
'//'
```

Answer (score 3):

This code works for me

```
  $text = "replace \ backslash";
  $rep = "";
  $replace_text = preg_replace( '/\\\\{1}/',$rep,$text);
  echo $replace_text;
```

**Output :**

replace backslash

Answer (score 2):

Escape `\` with `\`: `\\`

```
preg_replace('/\\/', 'REMOVED BACKSLASH', 'sometest\othertest');
```

Answer (score 0):

Use it twice eg `\\`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove backslash from text and don't want to see it anymore. then use this php function. But if it is a double backslash it will only remove one. `stripslashes ($string)`