# php preg_replace and the \ character

Tags: php, regex

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [php preg_replace \](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2222643/php-preg-replace)

I am trying to replace all occurances of the "\" character with "_c" using preg_replace.

Here is some code I have tried:

```
$outputStr=preg_replace('/\/','_c',$inputStr);
$outputStr=preg_replace('/\\/','_c',$inputStr);
```

But the $outputStr ends up as NULL in both cases. What is the correct regular expression to get the "\" character?

Comment: i searched stackoverflow for this problem - i must of missed this one somehow! sorry!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to escape the slash in your string and your regex:

> To use backslash in replacement, it must be doubled (`"\\\\"` PHP string).

See http://de3.php.net/preg_replace. e.g.

```
$outputStr = preg_replace('/\\\\/','_c',$inputStr);
```

Answer (score 0):

you just miss one '\' :

```
$outputStr=preg_replace('/\\\/','_c',$inputStr);
```