# string manipulation in php to process directly or store in table

Tags: php

I frequently need to access the user text like post, tweet, articles etc.

These  contains `'` or `\` and I get trouble.

Even using the

`mysqli_real_escape_String` also does not help
`stripslashes($str)` also does not help

which are the function most suitable for this?

This is one of the case:

```
$tweet = 'Best way to en'd a nights of debauchery around here. The hot dogs here are beyond great the TOKYO DOG is probably my favorite one...that taste of teriya\ki...';
```

If I use this using above both methods , it even get stuck without any error.

Comment: Use PDO, it's 21'st century

Comment: What does "does not help" mean? What exactly (in code!) is it you are trying to achieve and where do your current attempts fail you?

Comment: @Alex: I got this suggestion from many, I dont have used it before so I fear porting to PDO in ongoing system

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try using the `htmlspecialchars` function around the tweet. It will convert the symbols and special characters into their HTML entities.

```
$tweet = htmlspecialchars($tweet);
```

Comment: Tried this, still issue persist

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
  $tweet = "Best way to en'd a nights of debauchery around here. The hot dogs here are beyond great the TOKYO DOG is probably my favorite one...that taste of teriya\ki...";
  echo $tweet;
?>
```

output is:

Best way to en'd a nights of debauchery around here. The hot dogs here are beyond great the TOKYO DOG is probably my favorite one...that taste of teriya\ki...

Answer (score 1):

A function to make strings in general safe doesn't exist. Strings containing special
characters aren't inherently unsafe or tricky. The unsafe and tricky comes from giving
them to another interpreter (e.g. MYSQL or a Browser) in their raw form. Now, how to
escape the strings depends entirely on your interpreter. In case of MYSQL you can use
PDO, but it your interpreter is different you have to use a different escaping construct.

You should also not think about it as changing the string, you should think about it as
formatting the string in a way so that it will have the same meaning in the new context
you are using it.

As an example, if something needs to be first put in a
database and then displayed in the browser you should escape it once just before you put it
in the database according to the database rules. Then when you fetch it from the db to
display in a browser you should escape it again according to the rules for how html is
interpreted.

To give specific advice regarding your situation we need a bit more info about where your
data corruption or errors occur.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: never mind, the htmlspecialcharacters answer is correct for escaping. My assumption below was wrong.

---

I'm assuming you need to get rid of those from the string.

preg_replace is your best bet, if you know you'll only get ' or \ in the string.

```
$tweet = preg_replace("/\'\\\\/","",$string);
```

Try [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2222643/php-preg-replace) if you have trouble.

Comment: No, there may be more such characters in text, do you have idea which other character creates this issue?

Comment: Yeah - look for characters like backticks ```, doublequotes `"`, forward slashes `/` as well.

Comment: Escaping things with regex are doomed to fail imo, or it has to be very very conservative. In addition you corrupt the data the user sent. I don't think you should do that if you have other options.

Comment: Yeah, but there's no easy way to get rid of special characters without it. Anyway it looks like he wanted to escape them, not remove them, so my original assumption was wrong.